# Ruby On Rails - Using model methods with Serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rest, serialization

I have a `patient` `model` where I defined:

```
def weight
  ###Some Code###
end

def height
  ###Some Code###
end
```

Inside my `patient` `serializer`, I am also sending both `height` and `weight` to my `angularJS` app when performing a `/GET`.

Now, willing to add some `date` `filters` to my `angularJS` app, I have to change my `patient` `model` methods to be this way:

```
def weight(date)
  ###Some Code###
end

def height(date)
  ###Some Code###
end
```

I was wondering if there is a possibility to tell my `RoR` app to send me both `weight` and `height` at a chosen `date`?

I was thinking about creating a new `Controller` to do the work but I want to avoid this if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make weight and height virtual attributes on the model.  They will be set in memory on the instance when you call setter methods. They should serialize as normal.  Something like:

```
class Patient

  attr_accessor :weight, :height

  def filter_weight(date)
    @weight = ### previous result of #weight(date) Some Code###
  end

  def filter_height(date)
    @height = ###previous result #height(date) Some Code###
  end

end
```

Then you would send the date as parameters in your GET request.

```
class PatientsController
  def show
    patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    patient.filter_weight(params[:date])
    patient.filter_height(params[:date])
    render json: patient, status: 200
  end
end
```

You could probably refactor this into a method Patient#filter_weight_and_height(date)